# I am using Chaquopy to use python and java interchangeably.How can I pass my custom java object to the python module's method?

Tags: java, python, chaquopy

I want to pass my custom java object to the python module as an argument to its method.

I have successfully imported Python module and already passed strings/arrays from java code.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. Just pass the Java object as a parameter to `PyObject.callAttr`. If you're having a specific problem then please say what it is.

Comment: Thank you @mhsmith.I did the same and on the python side ,used java cast to get equivalent python object.